# Unable to create Authorizer for REST API using passed Cognito User Pool from separate stack. What is the issue?

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-api-gateway

I have 2 stacks in total my WebFrontStack and my CRUD stack. I need to create a lambda authorizer for my rest API using my cognito user pool. My cognito user pool was created in the WebFrontStack and passed through my app.py to my CRUD-Stack for a cross stack reference. When I use the debugger there are no issues present, however run I try to deploy all stacks or run a synth command i'm given this error:

```
(.venv) C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3>cdk synth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\app.py", line 12, in <module>
    CRUDStack = CRUDStack(app, "CRUD-Stack", table=WebFrontStack.table)
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 86, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\ab3\crud_stack.py", line 44, in __init__
    auth = apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(self, "cognitoRESTAPIAuthorizer",
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 86, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\aws_apigateway\__init__.py", line 25584, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\__init__.py", line 290, in create
    response = self.provider.create(
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 344, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 311, in send
    data = json.dumps(req_dict, default=jdefault).encode("utf8")
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\fahaider\Documents\CDK\AB3\.venv\lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 151, in jdefault
    raise TypeError("Don't know how to convert object to JSON: %r" % obj)
TypeError: Don't know how to convert object to JSON: <class 'aws_cdk.aws_cognito.UserPool'>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is since before I was able to use the cognito userpool as a cross stack reference to create a REST API authorizer with this issue. The CDK Docs state that my syntax is correct as well. Has anyone else run into this issue? And if so how were you able to get around it? I listed the CDK docs and my stacks code as well as my app.py

[Cognito User Pools authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/README.html#cognito-user-pools-authorizer)

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import aws_cdk as cdk

from ab3.web_front_stack import WebFrontStack
from ab3.crud_stack import CRUDStack


app = cdk.App()

WebFrontStack = WebFrontStack(app, "web-front-stack")
CRUDStack = CRUDStack(app, "CRUD-Stack", table=WebFrontStack.table, pool=WebFrontStack.pool)

app.synth()
```

Stacks listed below:

```
web_front_stack.py
    from constructs import Construct
    from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    Stack,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_s3_deployment as s3deploy,
    aws_cloudfront as cloudfront,
    aws_cloudfront_origins as origins,
    aws_dynamodb as ddb,
    aws_cognito as cognito,
    aws_waf as waf,
    Stack,
    RemovalPolicy,
    CfnOutput
)


class WebFrontStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        ##S3 Bucket##
        # This is where the static website is hosted and all the files associated

        website_bucket = s3.Bucket(self, "WebsiteBucket", removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY, auto_delete_objects=True)

        deploy_site = s3deploy.BucketDeployment(
            self,
            "DeploySite",
            sources=[s3deploy.Source.asset("./website/")],
            destination_bucket=website_bucket
        )

        oai = cloudfront.OriginAccessIdentity(self, "AB3-OAI", comment="My OAI for the S3 Bucket Website")

        website_bucket.grant_read(oai)


        cd = cloudfront.Distribution(self, "myCloudFrontDistribution",
            default_root_object='index.html',
            default_behavior=cloudfront.BehaviorOptions(
                origin=origins.S3Origin(website_bucket, origin_access_identity=oai), 
                viewer_protocol_policy=cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS)
        )
        
        table = ddb.Table(self, "User-Table",
            partition_key=ddb.Attribute(name="username", type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING),
            billing_mode=ddb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST
        )

        cognito_to_ddb = _lambda.Function(self, "createUser",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambdas/cognitoToDDB"),
            handler="cognitoToDDB.lambda_handler",
            environment={
                'table_name': table.table_name
            }
        )
        table.grant_read_write_data(cognito_to_ddb)
        # create cognito user pool needed?
        pool = cognito.UserPool(self, 
        "my cognito user pool",
        user_invitation=cognito.UserInvitationConfig(
            email_subject="Invite to join our awesome app!",
            email_body="Hello {username}, you have been invited to join our awesome app! Your temporary password is {####}",
            sms_message="Hello {username}, your temporary password for our awesome app is {####}"
        ),
        self_sign_up_enabled=True,
        user_verification=cognito.UserVerificationConfig(
            email_subject="Verify your email for our awesome app!",
            email_body="Thanks for signing up to our awesome app! Your verification code is {####}",
            email_style=cognito.VerificationEmailStyle.CODE,
            sms_message="Thanks for signing up to our awesome app! Your verification code is {####}"
        ),
        standard_attributes=cognito.StandardAttributes(
            email=cognito.StandardAttribute(
                required=True,
                mutable=False
            )
        ),
        lambda_triggers=cognito.UserPoolTriggers(
                post_confirmation=cognito_to_ddb
        ),
        # mfa=cognito.Mfa.REQUIRED,
        # mfa_second_factor=cognito.MfaSecondFactor(
        #     sms=True,
        #     otp=True
        # ),
        sign_in_aliases=cognito.SignInAliases(
                username=True,
                email=True
        ),
        auto_verify=cognito.AutoVerifiedAttrs(email=True),
        account_recovery=cognito.AccountRecovery.EMAIL_ONLY
        )

        

        # Cognito User pool app client
        #     - Callback URL to the Cloudfront Domain
        #     - Authorization code grant
        #     - implicit grant
        #     - openid oauth scope

        #Add a client that cognito will redirect to the CloudFront distribution
        pool.add_client("app-client",
        o_auth=cognito.OAuthSettings(
            flows=cognito.OAuthFlows(
                implicit_code_grant=True
            ),
            scopes=[cognito.OAuthScope.OPENID],
            callback_urls=['https://'+cd.domain_name],
            logout_urls=["https://logout"]
            )
        )

        pool.add_domain("CognitoDomain",
            cognito_domain=cognito.CognitoDomainOptions(
                domain_prefix="ab3-serverless-webapp-opensearch"
            )
        )

        #make it available outside of this function
        self.table=table
        self.pool=pool
```

CRUD-Stack

```
from ast import Lambda
from weakref import proxy
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    Stack,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_s3_deployment as s3deploy,
    aws_cloudfront as cloudfront,
    aws_cloudfront_origins as origins,
    aws_cognito as cognito,
    aws_dynamodb as ddb,
    aws_apigateway as apigateway,
    aws_lambda as _lambda
)

class CRUDStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, table=ddb.Table, pool=cognito.UserPool, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        self.table = table

        getEntrys = _lambda.Function(self, "getEntrys",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambdas/getEntrys"),
            handler="cognitoToDDB.lambda_handler",
            environment={
                'table_name': table.table_name,
            }
        )

        table.grant_read_data(getEntrys)

        api = apigateway.RestApi(self, "CRUD-REST-API",
            endpoint_types=[apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL]
        )
        
        #Pull in the cognito user pool from the seperate Web Front Stack
        self.pool = pool

        #Create a new authorizer for the API gateway methods
        auth = apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(self, "cognitoRESTAPIAuthorizer",
            cognito_user_pools=[pool]
        )

        entrys = api.root.add_resource("entrys")

        entrys.add_method("GET", apigateway.LambdaIntegration(getEntrys),
            authorizer=auth,
            authorization_type=apigateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was declaring the passed dynamodb table and cognito user pool in the **init**. Instead of using this declaration:

```
table=ddb.table, pool=cognito.UserPool
```

You need to use this declaration:

```
table:ddb.Table, pool:cognito.UserPool
```

Not sure if this is because of newer version of CDK or Syntax error. The previous method worked on my other projects.